# No se encuentra el tipo System.ComponentModel.Component en el módulo System.dll

Tags: c#

Llevo unos días detrás de este error que no soy capaz de encontrar.

Es un proyecto creado en C# para las Hololens.

El proyecto es Holographic DirectX 11 App (Universal Windows). Estoy utilizando este proyecto ejemplo: [enlace](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/How-to-build-2d-app-in-9ee9eb4f/sourcecode?fileId=159864&pathId=98763852)

El proyecto tal y como viene, compila y se ejecuta bien en el emulador. El problema viene cuando importo una librería (DLL) específica. Esta librería está escrita en VB.NET. Al importarla me tira el siguiente fallo:

> ```
> Gravedad  Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
> Error     No se encuentra el tipo System.ComponentModel.Component en el módulo System.dll.    CS2DHololensApp C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets 352
> ```

He intentado buscar por más sitios pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: Esa libreria que importas probablemente no sea compatible con el tipo de proyecto que estas creando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que las universal app estan limitadas en cuanto a las librerias que pueden utilizar. Deberias validar las dependencias que esta libreria vb.net que incorporas es compatible con una universal app, quizas no puedas usarla

[.NET para aplicaciones UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/mt185501.aspx)

Ademas verifica si en este proyecto no se estan haciendo uso de `.NET Core`, con lo cuales si estarias limitado.

Recomendaria si tienes el codigo de la libreria .net que veas si puedes adaptarla para que se convierta a una Portable class library y asi poder usarla en este tipo de proyectos, aunque por el proyecto que usas de ejemplo deberias ver que soporte .net core

Comment: Utiliza .NET Core. Con Nuget instalé Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. Si lo quito, me pide todas las librerías de System.* (System.Int32, System.Void, etc.) que también las he intentado añadir pero no sé muy bien como hacerlo.

Comment: Esta claro que usa .net core, ahora el tema es porque necesitas usar esta libreria creada en vb.net? si tienes el codigo de la misma podrias ver de hacer compatible con .net core para poder integrarla a este proyecto de hololens. Recuerda que estas limitado al usar .net core, quizas debas exponer la funcionalidad por medio de un servicio web he invocar la funcionalidad de forma externa